# how to add up the column (cumulative sum) of the matrix in R?

Tags: r

I have a question about adding up the column of the matrix
for example:

```
I have a matrix
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    1
[2,]    2    4    2

I want it to be
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    5
[2,]    2    6    8
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can apply `cumsum` on each row by looping over the rows with `apply` and `MARGIN` specified as 1 and transpose the output

```
t(apply(m1, 1, cumsum))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    4    5
#[2,]    2    6    8
```

Or with a `for` loop

```
for(i in seq_len(ncol(m1))[-1]) m1[,i] <- m1[, i] + m1[, i-1]
```

Or another option is to split it a `list` of vectors with `asplit` and then `Reduce` with `+` and `accumulate = TRUE`

```
do.call(cbind, Reduce(`+`, asplit(m1, 2), accumulate = TRUE))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    4    5
#[2,]    2    6    8
```

---

or with a convenient function `rowCumsums` from `matrixStats`

```
library(matrixStats)
rowCumsums(m1)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    4    5
#[2,]    2    6    8
```

#### data

```
m1 <- cbind(1:2, 3:4, 1:2)
```